# In salesforce.stackexchange, on the questions page, why it is showing modified user instead of the user who created the question?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

i am seeing a curious behavior which have been implemented in salesforce.stackexchange recently which shows the modified user in the questions page instead of the user name who actually created the user. It is confusing who created the question. Please suggest is there a constructive reason of why it has been changed like that?

In the below screen shot, while Nivyaj is the actual user who created the question but it shows as Dominic as modified which is misguiding i think.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure (though I'd have to look it up to double check) that it's just an indication of what the last activity was on a question. Even when you comment on a question it'll push it back up to the top if you're on the "active" view.

Comment: This is correct, but I cannot find a link to back it up.